# Delete everything but a specific folder

Tags: terminal, rm

I am wondering what options I would pass to `rm -rf` to remove all but the `.git/` folder. I was reading the man pages but I got confused at the options you can pass in. If I wanted to remove all but the `.git/` what about the command be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use `find` to find all items in the directory that are *not* `.git` and then `rm` them:

```
> find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -name .git -print0| xargs -0 rm -rf;
```

Answer (score 1):

With bash :

```
shopt -s extglob
rm -rf !(.git)
```

[image: warning]

Take care to be in the good directory before running this command.

Check http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob

Comment: Is this a feature of a very recent version of bash? I can't get it to work in `GNU bash, version 4.1.16(8)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin)`.

Comment: Oh, I got it. You need to have the `extglob` option (set using `shopt -s extglob`) set for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using bash `GLOBIGNORE` variable to remove all files except specific ones

From the [bash(1)](http://www.manpager.com/linux/man1/bash.1.html) page:

```
A colon-separated list of patterns defining the set of filenames to be ignored
by pathname expansion. If a filename matched by a pathname expansion pattern
also matches one of the patterns in GLOBIGNORE, it is removed from the list
of matches.
```

To delete all files except zip and iso files, set GLOBIGNORE as follows:

```
GLOBIGNORE=*.git
rm -rf *
unset GLOBIGNORE
```

PS. only works with BASH

Comment: Mistake? `GLOBIGNORE` pattern is `*.git`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention the `.git/` directory, you are in a Git repository and could use `git` itself to remove folders and files:

```
git rm -r *
```

As desired, this would not remove the `.git` directory -- and if need be, you could also join this with `find`, `xargs`, `grep` etc. for a more precise selection of folders and files.

Also, perhaps hereafter you want to add and commit a new set of files:

```
git add --all
git commit -m "commit message"
```